# Invalid request parameter in Paypal API

Tags: perl, paypal

Hi I just picked up the code sample for perl and tried to do a payment to my sandbox developer test account with the following

```
sub promote {
    my $headers = HTTP::Headers->new(
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID'=> 'alexjaquet-facilitator_api1.gmail.com',
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD' => 'xxxxx',
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE' => 'An5ns1Kso7MWUdW4ErQKJJJ4qi4-  
                                      3fjxb5G1RfUPmQ5kIdwdsH7znTJ',
    'X-PAYPAL-SERVICE-VERSION' => '1.1.0',
    'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID' => 'APP-80W284485P519543T',
    'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT' => 'NV',
    'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' => 'NV');

 my $content = sprintf("%s&%s&%s&%s&%s&%s&%s&%s&%s&%s&%s&%s&%s&%s&%s", 
   'senderEmail=alexjaquet-facilitator@gmail.com',
   'actionType=PAY',
   'currencyCode=USD',
   'feesPayer=EACHRECEIVER',
   'receiverList.receiver(0).email=alexjaquet-facilitator@gmail.com ',
   'receiverList.receiver(0).primary=false',
   'receiverList.receiver(0).amount=20.00',
   'returnUrl=http:myreturnurl',
   'cancelUrl=http:mycancelurl',
   'requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US',
   'clientDetails.ipAddress=127.0.0.1',
   'clientDetails.deviceId=mydevice',
   'clientDetails.applicationId=PayNvpDemo');


my $req = HTTP::Request->new($method,'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments
                                      /Pay',$headers, $content);
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $res = $ua->request($req);
if ($res->is_success) {
    print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
print $res->content;}
else {
        print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
    print $res->status_line, "\n";}
```

}

but the response I get he's the following :

> error(0).domain=PLATFORM&error(0).subdomain=Application&error(0).severity=Error&error(0).category=Application&error(0).message=Invalid+request+parameter%3A+email+alexjaquet-facilitator%40gmail.com++is+invalid&error(0).parameter(0)=email&error(0).parameter(1)=alexjaquet-facilitator%40gmail.com+

Comment: Are those emails correct and added to the sandbox (also remove the space at the end of it, can't see that it would make any difference, but you never know)? Paypal API can be a bit fussy and its not always clear with their errors. I can't remember if you need the sender and receiver emails to be different as well, so maybe worth trying that as well.

Comment: Hi now I got no error message but the following message

responseEnvelope.timestamp=2013-11-25T13%3A04%3A36.542-08%3A00&responseEnvelope.ack=Success&responseEnvelope.correlationId=61bf2b4956e4a&responseEnvelope.build=7935900&payKey=AP-2WS965343L249625K&paymentExecStatus=CREATED

but In the balance I still have zero dollar is that normal ?

Comment: Its worth adding a comment as to what you did to fix the last problem, so others can find it. With the balance, I assume it depends on the payment, is it in the right currency, does it need to be accepted, the type of payment etc. It looks like it has made it fine though. You can normally use the payKey to look at a particular payment I think to see its status (via the weblogin).

Comment: I strongly suggest you use a module instead of duplicating work that has already been done. There's a variety of Paypal-related modules available on CPAN.

Comment: I fix the previous problem by using the correct email and trim whitespace.